# How to find the number of elements which share all the characteristics when there are many sets?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, recreational-mathematics

The problem is as follows:

> In a toddler's room there are 120 toys, 95 of them uses batteries, 86
>   have wheels, 94 are red color, 110 are made of plastic, 100 emit
>   sound. How many of the toys share all the characteristics?

I'm stuck at this situation since I don't know how should I build up the sets in order they can be arranged in such a way that I can made an intersection of all thus finding the answer. Can somebody help me to be in the right direction?

Comment: The question must be "*at least* how many" I should think.  To get started, can you do it if there are only two characteristics?  At least how many have wheels and use batteries?

Comment: @saulspatz I am not sure how to do that. Let's say that from those 86 which have wheels I can't assume that those all have batteries, since it is the smaller number I thought that but then what about those 95. Mind giving a hint?.

Comment: Sorry to take this long replying.  We have 86+95 = 181, and there are only 120 toys, so we must have counted at least 181-120 = 61 twice.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: 
\begin{eqnarray*}
b_1+a=95 \\
w_1+a=86 \\
r_1+a=94 \\
p_1+a=110 \\
s_1+a =100 \\
b_1+w_1+r_1+p_1+s_1+a=120
\end{eqnarray*}
add $4a$ to both sides of the last equation & ...

Edit :
To obtain the least value for the number of toys that has all $5$ popeerties ...

Let $a$ be the number of toys with all five properties.

Let $b$ be the number of toys with all the properties apart from needing batteries. etc ...

We have the following equations.
\begin{eqnarray*}
a &+& b &+&  w &+&  r &+&  p &+&  s &=& 120 \\
a & &  &+&  w &+&  r &+&  p &+&  s &=& 95 \\
a &+& b & &   &+&  r &+&  p &+&  s &=& 86 \\
a &+& b &+&  w & &   &+&  p &+&  s &=& 94 \\
a &+& b &+&  w &+&  r & &   &+&  s &=& 110 \\
a &+& b &+&  w &+&  r &+&  p & &   &=& 100 \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: If I follow your hint I end up with $91$ but that's not the answer, why the fourth equation has $1$ added to $p$?.

Comment: typo ... sorry about that $\ddot \smile$

Comment: I end up with $485=120+4a$ but this equation does not produce an integer neither is the answer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Round down to get the largest possible value for $a$.

Comment: Looking on the answer's sheet it says it is $5$ but I can't obtain that number from that equation as it's value is $91$. Therefore I don't think this is the right method for this problem in particular or maybe am I addressing it wrong?

Comment: Ah-ha! That was it. But why do you "eliminate" the term which encompasses the properties for each equation?. Is it because that property is included in the "a"?.

Comment: $w,r,p,s$ have the property of needing a battery, $b$ is the only quantity that does not.

Answer (score 1):

Using Venn diagram step by step:
$$\begin{align} &\underbrace{n(p/s)}_{20}+\underbrace{n(p\cap s)}_{90}+\underbrace{n(s)}_{10}= \\
&\underbrace{n(p\cap b/s)}_{20}+\underbrace{n(p\cap s\cap b)}_{65}+\underbrace{n(p\cap s/b)}_{25}+\underbrace{n(s\cap b/p)}_{10}= \\
&\underbrace{n(p\cap b\cap r)}_{20}+\underbrace{n(p\cap s\cap b\cap r)}_{39}+\underbrace{n(p\cap s\cap b/r)}_{26}+\underbrace{n(p\cap s\cap r/b)}_{25}+\underbrace{n(s\cap b\cap r/p)}_{10}= \\
&\underbrace{n(p\cap b\cap r\cap w/s)}_{20}+\color{red}{\underbrace{n(p\cap s\cap b\cap r\cap w)}_{5}}+\underbrace{n(p\cap s\cap b\cap r/w)}_{34}+\underbrace{n(p\cap s\cap b\cap w/r)}_{26}+\underbrace{n(p\cap s\cap r\cap w/b)}_{25}+\underbrace{n(s\cap b\cap r\cap w/p)}_{10}.\end{align}$$

Addendum: $A\B=A-B$ is a relative complement.

Imagine there are $120$ toys of only two kinds: $110$ plastic and $100$ sound. The minimum number of toys that share both characteristics is $90$ as indicated in the first Venn diagram (first expression). We move the numbers away from each other as much as we can. Then imagine $95$ toys with batteries are added. Again you indicate it in Venn diagram by the same logic.

Yes, I agree, it could be not the best (easiest) way to solve the problem. Well, my teacher used to say: "You better solve one problem in $10$ different ways rather $10$ similar problems in one way".

Comment: How do you get things like $n(p\cap s)$?  I believe you are assuming that each toy only lacks one characteristic, but you should make that explicit.  It could be that there is one toy lacking all the characteristics, which would increase the number that have them all.

Comment: @RossMillikan, the criteria is to minimize the number of toys that share all characteristics (the max is obviously $86$). As I said I am using Venn diagram step-by-step in the order: $p,s,b,r,w$. The final Venn diagram is consistent with your calculation: $n(all)=120-20-34-26-25-10=5.$ Thank you for commenting.

Comment: @farruhota I'm not very fond of the set theory notation that looks like a division. Could it be that it means a symmetric difference?. I'd like you could add a bit of more explation how did you come to the conclusion for the terms in the brackets. For example, What is the meaning in words of $p\,\cap b/s$?. You mentioned the maximum that share all characteristics is $86$ which kind of makes sense as is the "minimum number" given from the data provided. But it is the way how you put it in Venn diagram which is I'd like you could add some words into it.

Answer (score 1):

The simple approach is that the minimum number that have all the characteristics comes when the ones that don't have all the characteristics are only missing one each.  There are $25$ without batteries, $34$ without wheels, $26$ not red, $10$ not plastic, and $20$ do not emit sound.  The minimum number that share all the characteristics is then $120-25-34-26-10-20=5$