# How to find the least number of objects in a set involving gender?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, arithmetic, recreational-mathematics, word-problem

The problem is as follows:

> At Emily's birthday, Charlie counted the number of all the women who
>   participated on the celebration. He found there were only three
>   mothers, three daughters, two grandmothers, two grand daughters, one
>   great grandmother and one great grand daughter. What is the least
>   number of women in Emily's birthday?

I'm not sure if this is any trick in problem other than just gender, but what I did was what I felt obvious, to pick one from each group.

Hence:

$\textrm{Mother = 1}$

$\textrm{Daughter = 1}$

$\textrm{Grandmother = 1}$

$\textrm{Granddaughter = 1}$

$\textrm{Great grandmother = 1}$

$\textrm{Great granddaughter = 1}$

Thus the sum is $6$ for the least number, but Is this the right interpretation or I ignored some details?.

Comment: The classes aren't disjoint: grandmothers are mothers, great grandmothers are mothers and grandmothers. Try doing the sums for the scenario with $A$ who is the mother of $B$ who is the mother of $C$ who is the mother of $D$!

Comment: *All* women are daughters, granddaughters and great-granddaughters, so it shouldn't be possible for the number of daughters to be different from the number of granddaughters or great-granddaughters. Does "daughter" in this problem mean "daughter of another participant"?

Comment: @RobArthan From the way how this problem is stated should it be a good idea to put it in a Venn diagram?. I'm confused at this point because I don't know how to relate it with the sums you mentioned.

Comment: @hvd How can I translate that into a mathematical expression? It comes to my mind the idea of inclusion but I don't know how to make operations with those.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell Since I do not know what the English text actually means (hence my request for clarification), I am not capable of translating it to anything else.

Comment: @hvd From looking into my book it doesn't seem to be clear about that. Would it make any difference if we assume that is from another participant other than those mentioned?. In that case maybe it would be disjoint. But I feel it does not seem to be situation here.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is at least $4$ women. Imagine than $A$,$B$,$C$,$D$ are $4$ distinct women.  $A\rightarrow B$ means A is the mother of B.

Consider,
$A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C\rightarrow D$

A is a great grand mother;
A,B are grand mothers; 
A,B,C are mothers.

The daughter relation is the `reflection` of the mother relation so you do not even need to check for the daughters.

Indeed if you order the information you have from great grand mother to great grand daughter you can see the symmetry of the problem.

**Generalization:**

Consider you have $1$ predecessor of degree $k$ and $2$ predecessors of degree $k-1$, $\dots$, $k$ predecessors of degree $1$

Well, it is exactly the same as considering that you have $1$ successor of degree $k$ and $2$ successors of degree $k-1$, $\dots$, $k$ successors of degree $1$.

The least number of person you need is k persons all recursively related to each other.

Comment: I totally missed that part. Is there a way to show what you mentioned into a Venn diagram or some kind of visual aid?. I mean I can't imagine how is it. I am also curious on which other kind of situations can this happen?. I'm a bit stuck at trying to understand with the degree $k$ you mentioned. Which is the $k-1$?.

Comment: Being an ancestor of degree 1 means being a mother, order 2 is grand mother and so on is that makes sense? I ll try to find a more visual way to look at it.

Comment: Okay I understood about the degree, the word order was more logical. I believe that the answer can be greatly improved if it has a diagram as I can't think how it could be one. At this point I can only think that this specific kind of solution is applicable to this kind of problem, but can it be extended to other situations other than chronological order of things. I previously asked (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2665013/how-to-find-the-number-of-elements-which-share-all-the-characteristics-when-ther) would this approach be applicable in that scenario?.

Comment: I do not think I have the background to conceptualize nicely these two problems and generalize by heart right away.  But I will look into it. In the mean time you could try to formalize / generalize the problem and create another thread. A more formal/general question will attract more generic answers hopefully